# How do I manually install Feed the Beast Unhinged?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

FTB Unhinged looks like its the mod pack I would like to run on my server. My server's control panel has a nifty mod installation section where it gives me a drop-down that lets me click whatever mod pack I wish to install and it does it for me. However, Unhinged is not on the list of mods it installs for me.

How do I, step by step, install Feed the Beast Unhinged. IE: What order to I install the mods that are listed in the pack, and other than putting them in their respective forge folder, is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: Do you have any ability to upload zip files or access the file system of the server?

Comment: @sevensideddie yes, and your second comment basically answered my question. thanks very much!

Comment: Cool! I'll refocus it on that comment's content when I've got a few minutes to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able to upload individual mods to your server [the Unhinged announcement post](http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/new-mod-packs.26682/) links to [a maintained list of included mods](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0AoWBpEX_gP1AdEh4Ulo1NUhqZ01Ybm0tMllUNDFpQ0E&toomany=true#gid=0).

A major virtue of Forge is that install order is almost never a problem when you're dealing with pure Forge mods. The mods themselves will have install instructions that should be checked in case there is anything special, but in general Forge jar mods can be installed in any order after Forge. Coremods and plain mods go in a folder to be loaded by Forge at launch, and don't conflict. Very few or none will be jar mods anyway, and order can't matter for the rest. What you have to watch for is ID conflicts in the config files.

Note that this modpack is intended to have customised configs to make it "hard mode", so once you've installed all the mods you'll still have to download the actual Unhinged distribution and consult/copy over the config files to properly set up your recreation of Unhinged.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question, I know what mods are listed in the pack, what i don't know is how to install each individual mod and in what order to install them. IE: some are jar mods, and some are 'mod folder' mods, and what order i should install the jar mods

Comment: @Ender That's an important detail to put in your question. The mods themselves have install instructions, but in general Forge jar mods can be installed in any order after Forge. Coremods and plain mods go in a folder to be loaded by Forge at launch, and don't conflict. What you have to watch for is ID conflicts in the config files. Install order is a non-problem when you're dealing with pure Forge mods. Very few or none will be jar mods anyway, and order can't matter for the rest.